# ngGrid scroll vertically keeps jumping back up

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

This bug happens on IE9, it probably happens in earlier version of IE as well. 
The bug cannot be reproduced on Chrome.

ngGrid, scrolling with mouse does not scroll the page down. It keeps jumping back to same location. You need to use the scroll bar on browser edge to get down the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the `ngGridDirectives.directive'ngViewport'` in the `ngGrid js`.

It tries to focus on 'top' element, and this causes flickering/jumping.

Solution: Look for element bind `mousewheel`

```
elm.bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function() {
    isMouseWheelActive = true;
    // if (elm.focus) { elm.focus(); } <-- comment out this line
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Worked well for me!