# Using angularJs to modify css.height causes Internet Explorer to not scroll to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

When i try to dynamically set the height of a `ngGrid` component (using `ngFlexibleHeightPlugin`) I can't use the mousewheel to scroll to the bottom of the page in Internet Explorer 11 (and lower).

The issue only appears on heights larger than the screen size and only when using the mousewheel to scroll.

The critical line of code is:

```
self.grid.$viewport.css('height', newViewportHeight + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mousewheel()` function in the `ng-grid.js` is causing the issue for the `Internet Explorer`.

If you are comment the following block `if (elm.focus) { elm.focus(); }` from the `ng-grid.js`, it will solve the issue.

```
function mousewheel() {
    isMouseWheelActive = true;
    //if (elm.focus) { elm.focus(); }
    return true;
}
```

Help from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25171252/2451726